# png_read_image access violation?

Tags: c++, png, libpng

I keep getting `Access violation writing location 0x....` errors when calling `png_read_image`. Here's my code

```
unsigned int bytesPerRow = png_get_rowbytes(_pngPtr, _pngInfoPtr);
_pixels = new unsigned char[bytesPerRow * _height];

png_read_image(_pngPtr, &_pixels);
```

Note that `png_read_info` has been called before, successfully.
I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. The documentation says nothing interesting about that function, so it shouldn't be too complicated.

Comment: It's because `&_pixels`  is the address of a pointer, i.e. a pointer to a pointer, so it is equivalent to a `png_bytep row_pointers[1]` (there is only 1 pointer) instead of the expected `png_bytep row_pointers[height]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`png_read_image` expects an array of row pointers, rather than a pointer to the raw data buffer. In other words, there must be one such pointer per row.

Now you can still use the same `_pixels` as the buffer holding the data, but you must provide a `_row_pointers` array which instructs `png_read_image` where the rows are in that buffer. Assuming you want to store the data in row order within that `_pixels` buffer, each row will start at an address that is `bytesPerRow` from the previous one, or `i*bytesPerRow` from the start of the `_pixels` buffer.

You can thus create that array of row pointers with:

```
_row_pointers = new png_bytep[_height];
for (int i=0; i<_height; i++)
{
  _row_pointers[i] = _pixels + i*bytesPerRow;
}
png_read_image(_pngPtr, _row_pointers);
```

where `_pixels` has been allocated as a continuous block of memory as you have done with `_pixels = new unsigned char[bytesPerRow * _height];`

Comment: can you explain that line? `_row_pointer[i] = _pixels + i*bytesPerRow;`

Comment: I saw your edit. Still about that line: what does `_pixels` have to do with any of this? Until that point, `_pixels` is an uninitialized pointer to bytes.

Comment: A correction: `_pixels` is a pointer to an unallocated array of bytes.

Comment: @Pilpel hope this latest updates clarifies your question about `_pixels`

Answer (score 1):

After you have called png_set_something(), then call png_read_update_info(), then bytesPerRow = png_get_rowbytes().

If you call png_get_rowbytes() right after png_get_IHDR() and then set any transforms after that, your bytesPerRow might be too small and you'll get an access violation.

EDIT 3 July 2017: I've just pushed this revision to the libpng documentation (libpng.3, libpng-manual.txt):

```
    rowbytes       - number of bytes needed to hold a row
+                     This value, the bit_depth, color_type,
+                     and the number of channels can change
+                     if you use transforms such as
+                     png_set_expand(). See
+                     png_read_update_info(), below.
```